# Why i cant compare my input in C to a regular text?

Tags: c

I'm trying to compare a regulare text to my input and if this specific condition is happening i want to print something, if not, just keep running.

This is the code:

```
int main()

{
    int c;
    c = getchar();

    while (c != EOF)

    {
        putchar(c);

        if (c == 'nir')
        {
            printf ("you typed nir");
        }

        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

Comment: An `int` is an integer. It can't hope to compare properly against strings.

Comment: This is homework isn't it. If so they probably expect you to have either an array (or a circular buffer) of the last three characters and compare them to the target word "nir" or to create an automaton that keeps track of the "nir" target word. If this is not homework... no I will not think of this.

Comment: could someone please show me a simple comparison that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little too confused for me to answer it all at once, so let's begin at the beginning.  To begin, `'nir'` (if it compiles at all) is a very strange way to write a single integer, whereas I think that you meant `"nir"`, a string of text.  However, `(c == "nir")` does not compile, does it?  [This presumably is why you have tried `(c == 'nir')` as a random shot, isn't it, though it means nothing sensible in C.]

In the context in which you use it, the `"nir"` is an *address.*  Now, you probably don't know what this means yet -- nor will you until you have gained several weeks' more experience in C.  What you can use today is the standard library's `strcmp()` function, presented by *string.h.*  I would recommend that you look that up and go from there.

And don't type `'nir'` again, incidentally!  It means nothing sensible in C.  The single quotes are for a single character like `'n'`, and stand for the character's integral ASCII value.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a string with a character. Instead of using getchar try to get the string.

```
char str[100], line[500];
```

1) Read a line using fgets.

```
fgets(line,100, stdin)
```

2) Use sscanf to obtain the string.

```
sscanf(line,"%s", str);
```

3) use strcmp to compare string.

```
if(strcmp(str,"nir") == 0) 
    printf("You entered nir ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main()
{
char c;


int i = 0;
do
{
     c = getchar();
     switch(i)
     {
         case 0: 
               if(c == 'n')
               {
                 i++;
               }
                break;
         case 1: 
               if(c == 'i')
               {
                 i++;
               }
               else
               {
                  i = 0; 
                }
                break;
         case 2: 
               if(c == 'r')
               {
                 printf ("you typed nir");
               }
               i = 0; 
               break;
      }
 }while (c != EOF);
 }
```

Try this code